# Hi, so I find olympiad geometry really difficult, ACM12.

Tags: geometry, soft-question, contest-math, analytic-geometry

I tried EGMO (Euclidean Geometry for Mathematical Olympiads) but I end up solving every problem using the same technique, bashing. Are there any ways to improve at synth geometry? Any YouTube channels which could help or something? I know so many formulae, even weird ones like Lagrange's identity and stuff like that yet when I see a solution I think: How could I have come up with this?

Comment: In the game of chess, it is good to study matches between masters: here, it is a similar advice: study on a **good solution book** that show **different methods** for solving a same problem. I don't think there is a better way...

Comment: Please make your question more specific. We aren't a discussion site, so if you focus on the types of problems you find hard or something else, your question will be a better fit for this site.

Comment: If you have qualified for the EGMO (European Girls' Maths Olympiad = not everyone is familiar with this), then you have at least made some progress. If you tell us a bit more about your skill level we can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to learn how to solve problems is to solve problems. You don't learn how to draw just by looking at paintings. You don't learn how to play the piano just by memorizing notes. You have to actually engage in the activity along with learning about the activity to truly master a skill. You also need to put in the time and effort as well. Here are some problem solving resources I use to practice my math skills.

https://artofproblemsolving.com/store Art of Problem Solving Books

https://artofproblemsolving.com/alcumus/problem Practice system that gives you lots of problems of various topics to solve.

Hope that helps.